# undefined method `change' DateTime in IRB console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

change(:hour => 1) working fine in rails console

```
irb(main):004:0> dt = DateTime.now
=> Mon, 10 Dec 2012 15:52:01 -0800
irb(main):005:0> _.change(:hour => 1)
=> Mon, 10 Dec 2012 01:00:00 -0800
irb(main):006:0>
irb(main):007:0> dt.class
=> DateTime
irb(main):008:0>
```

But throws “undefined method `change'” in irb

```
irb(main):008:0> require 'active_record'
=> true
irb(main):009:0> dt = DateTime.now
=> #<DateTime: 2012-12-10T15:55:14-08:00 (10611097185737/4320000,-1/3,2299161)>
irb(main):010:0> dt.class
=> DateTime
irb(main):011:0> dt.change(:hour => 1)
NoMethodError: undefined method `change' for #<DateTime:0x53e20a9a>
        from (irb):11:in `evaluate'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1070:in `eval'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1395:in `loop'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1178:in `catch'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1178:in `catch'
        from C:\PF\jruby-1.7.0.preview2\bin\irb:13:in `(root)'
irb(main):012:0>
```

Any suggestion how to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

To get the functionality related to datetime, Just `require 'active_support/time'`

Comment: Nice, thank you. It works. Please give me the tip how could I found resolution for problems like this by myself?

Comment: You can refer the rails guides [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Change is an active support method](http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/change), so to have it defined, you first have to require the library:

```
>> require 'active_support/all'
=> true
>> dt = DateTime.now
=> Tue, 11 Dec 2012 11:34:54 +0100
>> dt.change(:hour => 1)
=> Tue, 11 Dec 2012 01:00:00 +0100
```

Comment: Click the accept answer button if this solution worked for you.